# How to import apache.jena into Visual Studio Code?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, jena

I am getting started with Jena and semantic technologies (I am taking a class on the topic). The lecturer recommends using Eclipse as IDE, but I would like to use Visual Studio Code. How can I import apache.jena? I would like to get information/error messages as you would with any other library.

I have had amongst VSCode's extensions, but did not find any support.
I include "import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.*;" and get a "not found" error when I try to compile - unless I also include "-cp "/path/to/apacha/jena/on/my/computer/*:." when compiling and running the program.

The goal is to be able to compile and run without having to include a path to the library and if possible, for VSCode to have an understand of the library (giving me warnings, suggestions, error messages osv.)

Comment: So you want to turn VSCode it into a Java IDE via plugins? Seems like a bad idea, because actual Java IDEs like Eclipse (or even IntelliJ) are laser-focused on Java as opposed to being a generic editor and include tons of java specific functionality which will be hard to replicate. Not saying it's impossible, maybe VSCode and plugins got significantly better since I checked it out a few years ago, but it feels like you're setting yourself up for failure. I'd recommend simply checking out Eclipse or IntelliJ (and I say this as someone who writes all code _except_ java in vim).

Comment: Consult the documentation of the specific plugin you're using to see how you can add libraries to the classpath of your project. However, I would really recommend using IntelliJ or Eclipse.

Answer (score -1):

Use Java in VSCODE. You need to install the [**Extension Pack for Java**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack), and the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial) contains more information.

Use VSCode to open the Java project folder, expand the project structure and display it on the **JAVA PROJECTS** panel.

[image]

Click the plus icon next to *Referenced Libraries* to add a `.jar` file reference. Of course you need to download the Jena library on your machine first.

[image]

Or use the following configuration in setting to add reference.

```json
"java.project.referencedLibraries": [
    "/path/to/jena/lib/*.jar"
]
```

Comment: Manually referencing JAR files is a very brittle way to construct a Java project.  You would be much better off using a dependency manager like [Apache Maven](https://maven.apache.org) or [Gradle](https://gradle.org).  Jena has documentation on how to use it via [Maven](https://jena.apache.org/download/maven.html)